# I'm trying to create the same effect for the password, but it's not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the same effect for the [password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT2Z5.gif), but it's not working properly.

The username part is working fine, so I just used the same code from the username for password and change the selector to password classes.
[`CSS and HTML code`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLvqLJ)

How to fix this?

Comment: You can apply same class to apply for password  like  :       <div class="uname"> 
      <input type="password" class="user-input" id="pwd" required autocomplete="off" />
      <label class="user-label" for="pwd"><span>password</span></label>
   </div>

Comment: change the id for the password field and its label

Comment: For the future, please note the following: we prefer all information needed for answering in the question itself. Links to _supplemental_ resources are fine, but the question should make sense even if those links stop working. Furthermore, please avoid the phrase "not working properly" - it took a lot of time to figure out that it's not the yellow vs blue issue, or difference in borders, or any of the other things by which username differs from password in your example. Say exactly what is happening, and how it differs from the desired behaviour. You don't go to doctor and say "well, guess" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same `id` for password also.

Change the id to `pwd` and it works fine.

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/allanjebaraj/pen/NLpQmZ)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is copy-paste: you have two elements that have the same ID, `nme`, which is not really legal but browsers tend to be lenient. You also have two labels that both point at `nme`, which they can't differentiate, so they both point at the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id for both element, just change the id in second element.
Check updated snippet below:

```css
form {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

input,
span,
label {
  font-family: monospace;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/* MAIN EFFECT */
/* FOR USERNAME */

.user-input, .pass-input {
  font-size: 25px;       /* font size when typing */
  font-weight: 300;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 18%;            /* input border width */
  background: transparent;
  /*overflow-x: hidden; /* Hack to make "rows" attribute apply in Firefox. */
}

/* while not focus */
.user-input + .user-label, .pass-input + .pass-label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  width: 18%;                     /*width while not focus */ 
  border-bottom: 2px solid black; /* BOTTOM border & color */
  height: 30px;                   /* input border height */
  transition: width 3s ease;      /* line width transition */
  z-index: 1;
}

.user-label > span, .pass-label > span {
  position: absolute;    /* label position in front of input */
  color: black;          /* font color while not focus */
  font-size: 20px;       /* font size while not focus */
  top: 0px;              /* label position while not focus */
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: top 0.2s ease, font-size 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease; /* transition to go back */
}

/* lABEL while on top (focus)*/
.user-input:focus + .user-label > span, .user-input:valid + .user-label > span,
.pass-input:focus + .pass-label > span, .pass-input:valid + .pass-label > span
{
  top: -20px; 
  font-size: 15px;
  color: blue;           /* font color while on top */
}


.user-input:focus {
  background: yellow;
}
 
.pass-input:focus {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<form>

   <div class="uname"> 
      <input type="text" class="user-input" id="nme" required autocomplete="off" />
      <label class="user-label" for="nme"><span>Username</span></label>
   </div>

   <div class="pword"> 
      <input type="text" class="pass-input" id="pass" required autocomplete="off" />
      <label class="pass-label" for="pass"><span>Password</span></label>
   </div>   
  

  
</form>
```